# Is there any other base class which looks for a view other than System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

On ASP.NET MVC 3, assume that we have following controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index() {

    ViewBag.Message = "Foo Bar";
    return View();
}
```

Here, `Index` method is returning `ViewResult` instance which implements `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase` class. Because of the fact that we return instance of a `ViewResult` class, system tries to find a proper view file in order to generate an output. If it cannot find it, it will throw an exception.

My question is this:

**Is there any other base class which looks for a view other than `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase`?**

In plain English, do we have to return a class, which implements `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase` class, from controller action in order to render the result with a view?

**EDIT**

Also, as you see here I am telling that I will return a type of `ActionResult` which is the base, base class so to speak. When you look at the end, I am returning an instance of `ViewResult`.

How does framework handle that? Does it try to cast every controller action result to `ViewResultBase` class on the fly? I am really curious about this part especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ControllerActionInvoker` class is responsible for executing the controller actions. After finding and executing the action it looks for the action return type:

1. If the return type is `void` then it the creates a `EmptyResult`
2. If the return type anything but `ActionResult` then it converts the returned value to string and creates a `ContentResult` with that string.

So finally a result of an action is always an instance of the `ActionResult` class which declares the following method:

```
public abstract void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context);
```

Then the `ControllerActionInvoker` basically calls this `ExecuteResult` method to allow for the `ActionResult` to write to the `Reponse`. There is where in the case of `ViewResultBase` the view rendering is happening.
To answer your fist question in MVC3 only the descandants of the `ViewResultBase` class are rendering views.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Can you see my edit on the question. I am really curious about that part as well.

Comment: No it doesn't cast the controller action return value, just calls the `ExecuteResult` method on it. Which in the `ViewResultBase` implementation renders the view and writes it into the response.

Comment: Oww, so `ViewResultBase` class typically overrides the `ActionResult.ExecuteResult` method for its own needs, right?

Comment: Basically yes. So if you want a custom "`ActionResult`" it's enough to inherit from `ActionResult` and MVC3 will call your custom ExecuteResult  method.